# cannot see images in site hosted in github

Tags: github-pages

I´ve a problem with my site hosted in my Github account. Idon´t know how i need to specify the image´s direction in my CSS to charge them into my portfolio. Itried some of the advices but it didnt work. If someone can tell me what i need to change please tell me. Thank you.

My Github repository: https://github.com/AlexGA93/Portfolio_WD

My site hosted: https://alexga93.github.io/Portfolio_WD/

Comment: why don't you prepend all your links by https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlexGA93/Portfolio_WD/master/ ? ..not sure there is a better way :)

Comment: It´s fixed now. Thank you so much anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your relative to root url (**/path**):

```
<img id="foto-project" src="/images/biblioteca.jpg" >
```

For a relative to index.html url (**./path**) :

```
<img id="foto-project" src="./images/biblioteca.jpg" >
```